# baselines aren't aligned by using Erewhon Math font

Tags: fonts, opentype, lualatex-dev

By using "Erewhon Math" font on $\pm 2$ one observes that the baselines
of \pm and 2 aren't aligned unlike as with "Latin Modern" font

If I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
$\pm 2$
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

but if I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\begin{document}
$\pm 2$
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

I get the same behaviour with several other Open Type fonts.
How can I get the baselines aligned using an Open Type font?

Comment: There is no law that prescribes `\pm` to have the minus part on the baseline. Actually, I seem to remember to have answered exactly the opposite you’re asking, namely how to lower the `\pm` symbol so the plus part is aligned with a normal plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template defines an `\onbaseline` command that sets its argument’s depth to zero, while preserving its math spacing (`mathbin`, `\mathrel`, etc.)  You will notice that it does not necessarily preserve the kerning after .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\symdepth}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\onbaseline}[1]{%
   \settodepth{\symdepth}{$#1$}%
   \math@atom{#1}{\mathchoice%
     {\raisebox{\symdepth}{$\displaystyle #1$}}%
     {\raisebox{\symdepth}{$\textstyle #1$}}%
     {\raisebox{\symdepth}{$\scriptstyle #1$}}%
     {\raisebox{\symdepth}{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}}%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[ \onbaseline{f} \onbaseline{\pm} \onbaseline{2} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Erewhon Math sample]